# Google Sheet multiple lookup values and return entire row

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to lookup the activation type in C6 as well as the date range found in L6 and O6 on the "dashboard" tab and return the resulting rows (specifically columns E-J) from the "batches" tab?

[Example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W4gmquBdtrRiZKD3oKayswEtZOYVJQVlKl8EEq3GvAI/edit?usp=sharing)

You can see in C17, I've been able to return a single value based on one lookup value, but would like to expand to lookup multiple values and return the entire row?

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(L$6,Batches!A:A,Batches!E:E),"no live activations for that date range")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `FILTER` would best suit your purpose. Try replacing your current C17 formula with this one:

`=FILTER(Batches!E2:E,Batches!A2:A>=L6,Batches!A2:A<=O6,Batches!C2:C=C6)`